# Non-convergent integral converging after variable transformation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I try to integrate the following function with Integrate[...]

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1-x}{x} \right)^i$$

with $i$ the imaginary unit, mathematica says that it is not convergent. But after a change of variables $z=\frac{1-x}{x}$ with $dz=-\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\infty} dz \frac{1}{z(1+z)}z^i$$

which mathematica now evaluates to $-i \pi (\sinh(\pi))^{-1}$.

How is this possible?

Comment: The result of the first integration in Mathematica (including 12.2) is incorrect. In fact, this integral converges at both `0` and `1`.

Comment: Also note that `Integrate[1/(1 - x) ((1 - x)/x)^(a + I), {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 1 > a > 0]` yields `-I \[Pi] Csch[\[Pi] - I a \[Pi]]`, which approaches the limit of $-i\pi/\sinh(\pi)$ as $a \to 0$.

Comment: Applying your transformation to my "regularized" integral in the previous comment, we have `Integrate[z^(a + I)/(z (1 + z)), {z, 0, \[Infinity]}]` which yields `ConditionalExpression[-I \[Pi] Csch[\[Pi] - I a \[Pi]], Re[a] > 0]`—i.e., the `ConditionalExpression` yielded here doesn't apply to the $a = 0$ case.

Comment: @user64494:  Are you sure about the convergence at `1`?  Writing $z = (1-x)/x$, the integrand becomes $[\cos(\ln z) + i \sin(\ln z)]/(1-x)$.  The numerator will always have magnitude 1 while the denominator diverges proportionally to $1-x$, which seems conducive to logarithmic divergence to me.  (Or have I not been sufficiently careful when manipulating complex exponents?)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Indeed, the result of `ComplexExpand[Normal[Series[1/(1 - x) *((1 - x)/x)^I, {x, 1, 2}]]]` includes `(E^-Arg[1 - x] Cos[1/2 Log[(1 - x)^2]])/(-1 + x)` and `(E^-Arg[1 - x] Sin[1/2 Log[(1 - x)^2]])/(-1 + x)`. The integrals of these terms from`1/2` to `1` diverge. My statement about the convergence at `1` is not grounded and,likely, is not true.